# How can I shuffle the elements of two arrays with a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are two arrays, I need to get all possible options for shuffling them, but with one condition. You can take only the first element of each array for shuffling, after which this element is deleted. How can this be implemented?

Comment: Sorry @XXL, this isn't clear for me. Q1: You have 2 arrays: Do you want to obtain a single array with shuffled elements? Q2: what do you mean by 'you can take only the first element of each array for shuffling'? what kind of shaffling mechanism is that? You see, when i shaffle, i don't care for the first or the last item, i just take the array and reposition as randomly as possible its items... you need to use the first item for comparison, somehow?

Comment: @strongmmc 
I'll give you an example:
Result: []
First array [1,2,3]
Second array [4,5,6]
You can take only the first element of one of the arrays to put it in the shuffle result, i.e. 1 or 4.
Result: [4]
First array [1,2,3]
Second array [5,6]
Now you can take 1 or 5.
At the same time, I need to get not one variant of such a shuffle, but all variants, I don't even know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only 2 arrays, and you can take only the first element, there isn't many possibles options, but only one.
And for this is a simple implementation :

```js
[array1, array2] = [ [ array2[0] ], [ array1[0] ] ];
```

For exemple if you have :

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];
const array2 = ["a", "b", "c"];
[array1, array2] = [ [ array2[0] ], [ array1[0] ] ];

console.log(array1);  // ["a"]
console.log(array2);  // [1]
```

- `array1[0]` get the first element of array (you can read it like : element at index 0 of array1).
  So you will get for this exemple the value `1`.
- Then you put this element inside a new array : `[ array1[0] ]`
  So you have a new array with just the first element, and get rid of the rest like you wanted : `[1]`.
  There is others ways to do it, for example : `array1.slice(0, 1)`.
  this will return a new array with the element for index 0 to 1 of array1.
- `[array1, array2] = [ [ array2[0] ], [ array1[0] ] ];` is now equivalent of `[array1, array2] = [ ["a"], [1] ];`.
  It's called a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

It's almost the same as writing :

```
array1 = [ array2[0] ];
array2 = [ array1[0] ];
```

But if you do that, array1 and array2 will be the same, because you get the value of array1 after it's reassignment.
So you have to pass through a third variable :

```
const tempValue = [ array1[0] ];
array1 = [ array2[0] ];
array2 = tempValue;
```

Same result, but it's more simple ans more elegant to use :

```
[array1, array2] = [ [ array2[0] ], [ array1[0] ] ];
```